# Javascript: Phoenix channel immediately enters errored state

Tags: javascript, phoenix-framework

In my webapp I connect  to a Phoenix channel with Javascript.

```
  this._channel = socket.channel("user:" + username, {password: password})
  this._channel.join()
  .receive("ok", this._handleLoginSuccess.bind(this))
  .receive("error", this._handleLoginFailure.bind(this))
  .after(10000, () => console.log("Networking issue. Still waiting..."))
```

The `join` is handled successfully by the server and the `_handleLoginSuccess` callback is invoked correctly. But when starting the JS debugger and looking at `this._channel`, it is already in the "errored" state as soon as that callback is invoked and I cannot push any messages to it either. Yet I also see that `joinedOnce` is set to true, so something must be going very wrong indeed there.

Since the server side doesn't report any errors I'm wondering what's happening. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem: it was related to the live reload mechanism which somehow caused the websocket to be terminated and re-established all the time. After disabling live reload by commenting the lines below, my regular channel worked fine again.

```
#if code_reloading? do
#  socket "/phoenix/live_reload/socket", Phoenix.LiveReloader.Socket
#  plug Phoenix.LiveReloader
#  plug Phoenix.CodeReloader
#end
```

Comment: I think I was having the same issue, and this also got around it. Though a better understanding of what isn't working would be nice. I'll report back if I ever learn anything.